# Raising and lowering brightness using touchpad gestures on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, touchpad, brightness

I am trying to configure custom gestures on my Acer laptop with a touchpad.

I have already configured three-finger up and down to be volume up and down, respectively, from windows touchpad settings, specifically the Advanced Gesture configuration. I have also configured the three-finger tap to be mute, by recording Fn+F8 on my keyboard, and it works, [even though it shows up as a D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Q2J.png).

I am trying to do the same, to configure swiping left and right to be brigtness up and down, respectively. However, whenever I hit record and press Fn+RIGHT ARROW, it simply increases the brightness, without recording it.

Is it possible to force Windows to record these keypresses, or manually write it in e.g. using the registry?

Answer (score 2):

hey i finally figured out using the app "gesturesign" on microsof store, this is a much simpler app compared to alternatives. it's also free. I'm personally using four finger brightness up/down. Make sure to use 'continuous gesture', also there are settings that can be customized.